# "image format unsupported" for face detect in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, azure-cognitive-services

I'm unable to get my detect request to work in my flutter app.
I keep getting the response:

`{"error":{"code":"InvalidImage","message":"Decoding error, image format unsupported"}}`

- I am sending local jpg image data.
- I have tried clients from the `Dio` and `http` packages.
- I have gotten the endpoint to work using python.

Here's how I'm getting the image using the `camera` package:

```dart
var cameras = await availableCameras();
final frontCamera = cameras.firstWhereOrNull((c) => c.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.front);
if (firstCamera == null) return;
cameraController = CameraController(
    firstCamera,
    ResolutionPreset.high,
    enableAudio: false,
    imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.jpeg,
);
XFile file = await cameraController.takePicture();
```

Here's how I make the request using `Dio`:

```dart
final String url = 'https://[identifier].cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/detect';
final String subscriptionKey = [subscription key];

var response = await Dio().post(
    url,
    queryParameters: {
        'recognitionModel': 'recognition_04',
        'returnFaceId': 'true',
    },
    options: Options(
        headers: {
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey,
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        },
    ),
    data: file.readAsBytesSync(),
);
```

and here's the request using `http`. With `http` I get a 200 status code but the response body is completely empty. I'm not sure why that is.

```dart
final String url = 'https://[identifier].cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true&recognitionModel=recognition_04';
final String subscriptionKey = [subscription key];
final Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey,
};
final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(url),
    headers: headers,
    body: file.readAsBytesSync(),
);
```

I tried calling detect with local image data and the api is telling me that the image is not a valid format.
The image is jpg which is accepted according to the documentation, so I expected this to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was uploading the data incorrectly. With Dio apparently you need to upload data as a stream. So I changed the code to the following:

```dart
      var response = await _dio.post(
        '${Constants.faceApiUrl}/detect',
        queryParameters: {
          'recognitionModel': 'recognition_04',
          'returnFaceId': 'true',
        },
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': _subscriptionKey,
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
          },
        ),
        data: xfile.openRead(), // <---- Change Here
      );
```